# Writing functions on the right

Tags: mathematics, group-theory

In group theory, writing functions on the right is a common, though not universal practice.

Thus, given mappings $f$, $g$ and group element $\alpha$, one might write $\alpha f$ and $\alpha (f \circ g)$ for $f(\alpha)$ and $f(g(\alpha))$ respectively.

I can see how this makes sense in group theory, especially in relation to permutations.

I am unable to locate any information on when this practice was introduced and I suspect that it may be rather difficult to identify its origins.

**Q**: When was the practice of writing functions on the right introduced in group theory?

Comment: Related: [History of $f \circ g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132967/13130)

Comment: The instance of this I know:  if $\sigma$ is an automorphism of a field, then write $x^{\sigma}$ for the image of element $x$ under $\sigma$.  So composition is opposite to the usual:  $x^{\sigma \tau} = (x^\sigma)^\tau$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Hi Gerald, Yes, I've seen that notation myself. A previous comment, now deleted, cited a 1929 paper by Noether where she writes group operators on the right.  I suspect that this may be the source of the practice of writing mappings on the right in group theory.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thanks for your reference and congratulations on having such a sound memory  -  recalling a posting from 2012.

Comment: As far as memory, that was google. I knew that on several occasions I've mentioned Herstein used an order backwards than standard in his **Topics in Algebra** book, so I googled my name along with Herstein and composition, then I picked the most significant of the results (in terms of answers and discussion). It was only *after* I'd written my comment that I realized you were talking about where to place the $x$ (I hadn't realized this in my quick glance at your question before googling), so I then edited "See" (or whatever I began with) to "Related".