# Where does the "operator to the right" notation originate?

Tags: notation, linear-algebra

If any of you have ever written code in DirectX, you're sure to have noticed that applying a linear operator $A$ to a vector $x$ is done as $xA$, instead of the (nowadays usual) $Ax$. I wanted to know when this notation started to be used or from which areas of math it comes from.

I remember reading an old optimization paper once where they used this order for linear algebra, or a book introducing some logic concepts for Prolog (forgot which one it was) that also used some kind of logical operators and they were written as $a\theta$, where $\theta$ is the operator.

Idk if this is used in any other fields nowadays. My guess for why DirectX still uses is because of legacy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing functions on the right](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11192/writing-functions-on-the-right) where , in a now deleted comment, it was suggested that the practice was introduced by Noether.

Comment: The logic example you mention may be related to Reverse Polish Notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation which is relatively recent.

Comment: Herstein in his book on Abstract Algebra religiously followed this practice.

Comment: This was a notational convention advocated by algebraists in the 1960s (maybe earlier, I don't know).  The justification for this notation was to look more consistent with the way functions and their compositions are written in commutative diagrams: we think of mappings as going from left to right, and in this right operator notation the composition of a function $f$ followed by a function $g$ would be $f\circ g$ (since $(x)(f\circ g) = ((x)f)g$ rather than the usual notation $g \circ f$ (since $(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$).